# Eventstore connection blowing up memory usage and web app

Tags: c#, eventstoredb

We are connecting to our eventstore using EventStore.ClientAPI.NetCore from a .netcore web app. After around an hour of it being connected we suddenly get this error

"The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process."

And the subscription drops. We are using these retrying setups

```
settings.SetOperationTimeoutTo(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
settings.KeepRetrying();
settings.LimitReconnectionsTo(99);
```

Seeing if anyone else has had dropouts from subscribing to the Eventstore and seen this issue before.

Changing our subscription settings. Adding in polly around the retry which just made the issue worse.

Comment: at a min, switch to EventStore.ClientAPI 5.0.1 package to rule that out

Comment: The web app was on a S1 plan in azure and hitting a thread count of around 700 before dropping off, moved it up to a S2 plan and have been stable ever since.

Comment: in general even with serious load (I've used similar thread counts in load tests), ES isnt bothered by thread count, but like all things, at the limits of memory or CPU saturation, things can happen. [This config](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/f7d1625240fcaec5cad270a84c50739725fd0013/src/Equinox.EventStore/EventStore.fs#L653) has handled significant load in webapi but also in aspnetcore